# Oraclize: Difference between random methods

Tags: oracles

I write a smart contract and want to use oraclize for getting random number. Are there any differences between those methods:

Using WolframAlpha:

```
oraclize_query("WolframAlpha", "random number between 1 and 2^64");
```

Using Random.org:

```
oraclize_query(
     "URL",
     "json(https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/invoke).result.random.data.0",
     '\n{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"generateIntegers","params":{"apiKey":"9844ab4d-52ef-4587-9cf3-20a6930a7f6e","n":1,"min":1,"max":1000,"replacement":true,"base":10},"id":1}');
```

Using oraclize random method:

```
bytes32 queryId = oraclize_newRandomDSQuery(delay, N, callbackGas);
```

In term of price, I see that:

- WolframAlpha: 0.03$/query. unlimited queries.
- Random.org: 0.01$/query. only 1000 requests/day (limited by random.org)
- oraclize_newRandomDSQuery: 0.05$/query.

Please tell me differences in functionality.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The random data source query is designed so that assuming the ledger hardware enclave isn't compromised, your contract can verify that Oraclize really gave you a random number.

Using Wolfram Alpha or random.org require you to trust those organisations, plus Oraclize and their CDNs, any of whom could cheat undetectably.

Comment: thanks. so in production we should use random data source query, right ?

Comment: Yes, if you can afford it for your use-case. Or better, if possible design your thing so you don't have to use a third-party service...

Comment: Thanks so much :D I have a problem when using "oraclize_newRandomDSQuery" function. Can you help me to figure out. I ask here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/50857/oraclize-oraclize-newrandomdsquery-always-reverted
thanks