# Oraclize: oraclize_newRandomDSQuery always reverted

Tags: oracles

I'm using oraclize for generating random number for my smart contract. I have tested successfully with 2 methods:

- Using WolframAlpha
- Using random.org service

But when I try `oraclize_newRandomDSQuery`. My transaction always reverted. I don't know why Here is my code:

```
function _sendRandomQuery(uint256 _gasLimit) internal returns (uint256) {
           oraclize_newRandomDSQuery(0, 7, 200000);
           return 100;

}
```

Please tell me why.

Comment: If you add a link to one of the reverted transactions it would be easier to debug...